# Apache Solr: Setting HTTP Response Headers From solrconfig.xml For CORS

Tags: ajax, solr, http-headers, cors

Is it possible to setup the sending of a custom HTTP response header from within the `solrconfig.xml` file? I am thinking that it might be possible to add some configuration to the `<requestDispatcher>` section since it controls caching headers.

I am sure this is possible in the servlet container configuration (Jetty, Tomcat, etc.), but I would like to do this from within Solr's configuration files if at all possible.

If this makes any difference, I am attempting to set an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header for CORS AJAX requests from a different host.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use JSONP instead. See this link for an example

- [Solr and JSONP](http://xplus3.net/2010/09/21/solr-and-jsonp/)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I will definitely consider this for my fallback, but I would like to get real CORS working if possible.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to give you credit.  I finally implemented the solution and ended up going with JSONP since support for it is built into Solr.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way will be to write custom `javax.servlet.Filter` and add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header there. For code which handles HTTP processing see `org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter` class.

It IS the easiest way for you to proceed. If you look at the doFilter in SolrDispatchFilter - the only manipulation with HTTP Headers is to cache them and there's no place touching them in some way.

Answer (score 0):

front solr with apache, and conf apache to send back the header. For example,

```
Header set X-Server-Name "abc0.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://gist.github.com/Wavewash/70532f2cc945a830627e) helpful. You would need to add a couple of jetty jars and webdefault.xml change in order to enable CORS.

I am reproducing the text here:

---

In the example solr project when you start it up by calling the following line:

java -jar start

You are starting a Jetty server on your local machine that's going to serve the solr results. This server is not able to do CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing). Which means that if you tried to do an AJAX call from a webpage of a different origin than the server itself you would be denied a response.

To fix this you first need to get the apropriate jars to allow for cross-domain resource sharing.

I used the following jar:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlets/8.1.10.v20130312/

But you may need to get the version that's right for your version of jetty:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlets/

You can find out what version of Jetty you're running with your solr example by going:
java -jar start --version

and you'll see a dump as follows:
C:\Users\username\Desktop\solr-4.8.0\example>java -jar start.jar --version
Active Options: [default, *]
Version Information on 18 entries in the classpath.
Note: order presented here is how they would appear on the classpath.
      changes to the OPTIONS=[option,option,...] command line option will be reflected he
re.

```
0:                (dir) | ${jetty.home}\resources
 1:     8.1.10.v20130312 | ${jetty.home}\lib\jetty-xml-8.1.10.v20130312.jar
 2:  3.0.0.v201112011016 | ${jetty.home}\lib\servlet-api-3.0.jar
 3:     8.1.10.v20130312 | ${jetty.home}\lib\jetty-http-8.1.10.v20130312.jar
 4:     8.1.10.v20130312 | ${jetty.home}\lib\jetty-continuation-8.1.10.v20130312.jar
 5:     8.1.10.v20130312 | ${jetty.home}\lib\jetty-server-8.1.10.v20130312.jar
 6:     8.1.10.v20130312 | ${jetty.home}\lib\jetty-security-8.1.10.v20130312.jar
 7:     8.1.10.v20130312 | ${jetty.home}\lib\jetty-servlet-8.1.10.v20130312.jar
 8:     8.1.10.v20130312 | ${jetty.home}\lib\jetty-webapp-8.1.10.v20130312.jar
 9:     8.1.10.v20130312 | ${jetty.home}\lib\jetty-deploy-8.1.10.v20130312.jar
10:     8.1.10.v20130312 | ${jetty.home}\lib\jetty-servlets-8.1.10.v20130312.jar
11:                1.7.6 | ${jetty.home}\lib\ext\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.6.jar
12:                1.7.6 | ${jetty.home}\lib\ext\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.6.jar
13:               1.2.16 | ${jetty.home}\lib\ext\log4j-1.2.16.jar
14:                1.7.6 | ${jetty.home}\lib\ext\slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar
15:                1.7.6 | ${jetty.home}\lib\ext\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.6.jar
16:     8.1.10.v20130312 | ${jetty.home}\lib\jetty-util-8.1.10.v20130312.jar
17:     8.1.10.v20130312 | ${jetty.home}\lib\jetty-io-8.1.10.v20130312.jar
```

Look for the line that says  ${jetty.home}\lib\jetty-server (in the dump above it's line 5) and you should be able to see your version.

You'll also want to get the "jetty-util" for your jetty version too:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mortbay.jetty/jetty-util

You should be able to find your version there. I used jetty-util-8.1.10.v20130312.jar for mine.

Now take both the servlet.jar and util.jar files that you downloaded and place it into the following folder:
solr-4.8.0\example\lib

For your version it may be different but you want it in the lib folder under the example directory.

Finally, to allow these changes to take affect, you want to open up solr-4.8.0\example\etc\webdefault.xml

and add the following lines before `</web-app>`:

```
   <filter>
       <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
```

Now restart your server and you should have CORS enabled.

Notes:
If you start to get fancy and have multiple webapps running on the solr example jetty server then this will effect all those web apps. Be aware that you have set the url patter to recognize any domain which is dangerous for a production set up. This is for local testing only.

Also I did try to change the web.xml file in the webapps folder so that these changes would remain local but after hours of trying to get it to go, I gave up and found that putting it in the global webdefault worked.